# Ubuntu Social Integration on Login?

Tags: ubuntu, login, chat, social-networking

Quick one; Ubuntu recently integrated a social networks into the main panel, but by default you have to manually 'fire up' the chat and broadcast accounts after logging in.

Is there a way to set these so you automatically sign in to your pre-configured chat/broadcast accounts when you login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I'm not mistaken, the three players in this equation are Empathy for chat, Gwibber for microblogging/broadcasting, and Ubuntu One for cloud storage.  I'm sure that Empathy and Gwibber can be added to the startup items (under System >> Preferences >> Startup Items), and I know for sure that Ubuntu One is already in that list.

I know that's probably not as elegant a solution as what you were hoping for (a simple checkbox would be nice), and I also don't know whether launching these from the startup menu will open their respective windows or not, but at least it's a start.  Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: I had suspected that too, and have got most of the way there by setting a startup application `empathy -h`, as I don't want the chat menu to pop up, just for me to be logged in. 
Unfortunately I can't find a similar option for gwibber, but its better than nothing.